# How to assign variables from colon-separated text file c++

Tags: c++, filestream

I have a .txt file:

```
A:One:1:2:15.
B:Two:0:6:5.
C:Three:0:4:6.
D:Four:0:4:8.
E:Five:0:6:2.
```

And I need to read the file, and assign each value between the (:) to an appropriate variable.

Here is my code so far:

```
int main()
{
ifstream theFile("Parts.txt");

if(theFile.is_open())
{
    string line;
    while(getline(theFile, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);

        string code;
        string partName;
        int minimum;
        int maximum;
        int complexity;

        getline(ss, code, ':');
        getline(ss, partName, ':');
        getline(ss, minimum, ':');
        getline(ss, maximum, ':');
        getline(ss, complexity, ':');
        cout << code << partName << minimum << maximum << complexity << "\n";
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
a1.cpp:27:13: error: no matching function for call to 'getline'
        getline(ss, minimum, ':');

a1.cpp:28:13: error: no matching function for call to 'getline'
        getline(ss, maximum, ':');

a1.cpp:29:13: error: no matching function for call to 'getline'
        getline(ss, complexity, ':');
```

I'm quite new to c++ so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ read file colon separated value" or "C++ read file CSV".   There are over a plethora of these questions both on StackOverflow and the internet.

Comment: Look at the declarations for `std::getline`.  Notice that `code` and `partName` are strings, but `minimum`, `maximum`, and `complexity` are not strings; and yet these are what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: You could use `char colon;` then after reading partName use something like `ss >> minimum >> colon;`.

Comment: `string minimum_str; getline(ss, minimum_str, ':'); minimum = stoi(minimum_str);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getline(ss, minimum, ':');
```

The second parameter to `std::getline` is always a `std::string`. `minimum` is not a `std::string`. It is an `int`, this is why this fails to compile. When calling a function in C++ all parameter types must be correct, or convertible (implicitly or by a user-specified conversion operator) to the parameter types that the function expects.

You need to extract this word into a `std::string`, too, then use the [`std::stoi` library function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert a `std::string` into an `int`eger.